why my build.gradle.kts using java in android studio has this kind of error?
Image of error in Android Studio
i want to implement google maps but it keeps display error "Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)". please help to fix this
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:20.0.0'

Variable 'implementation' must be initialized//error

You're mixing Groovy and Kotlin notation there.
Kotlin needs the brackets and double quotes eg
implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0")

